# Stair stabilization

Tags: framing

Opened wall to make storage under stairs in basement. We have floating walls, the stringers are nailed to the walls, one side on concrete wall. There are 2 2x4s, one on each stringer, left and right, about mid way down the stringers which extend from the floor to the stringers as stabilizers, do I need them or can I remove?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to suggest whether the 2x4 support legs can be removed or not. There are just too many factors to consider that were not included in your query. Some of these factors include:

1. Overall length of the stringers.
2. Number of stringers used.
3. Width of the stairway.
4. Dimension of lumber used for the stringers.
5. Type of wood used for stringers.
6. Working load needed for the stairway.

Answer (score 0):

### You likely either need them or want them.

**Two cases**

1. needed
2. not needed

**Needed**

They were installed to deal with one or both of two reasons, to support the load or to add stiffness. If it was for stiffness, you could get away with removing them but your stairs would be bouncy and feel sketchy and uncomfortable even if there is enough strength. If installed for strength, it's then obvious why they are needed.

**Not Needed**

It is possible that they installed them for an abundance of precaution or because of 'that's how we always do it.' In which case they could be removed.

**Determination and Action**

However there is no way for us to be able to tell between the needed / not needed in your case without a lot more information. And I suspect that even that would not be enough, it might require on-site review and load tracing.

Unless you can determine otherwise, I suggest leaving them in place or providing an equivalent support which means to support the stringers in the same location and transfer that force to the same location under the 2x4s.